# Not able to bind MVC Model into Razor with Knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I know this should be very simple and there might be many article and example on this. But still, I am not able to make it work. Please try first if it's working before sending the solution, if you can. Also if you are using any lib or extension, then please do mention in your reply. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

My question - Not able to bind a MVC Model (IEnumerable), return by a controller Index, to PartialView.

Controller

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Books = db.BookDB.ToList();
    Authors = db.AuthorDB.ToList();
    objBookAuthorViewModel.Authors = Authors;
    objBookAuthorViewModel.Books = Books;
    return View("~/Views/Book/Index.cshtml", objBookAuthorViewModel);
}
```

Index View (Calls Partial view)

```cs
@model KnockOutJsMvcCreateArticle.Models.BookAuthorViewModel
@using KnockOutJsMvcCreateArticle.Models
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
....
<div id="_indexPartialAuthor">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="panel panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2 class="panel-title"># of Authors @Model.Authors.Count</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Author.cshtml", Model.Authors)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Partial View

```cs
@using KnockOutJsMvcCreateArticle.Models
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@model IEnumerable<KnockOutJsMvcCreateArticle.Models.Author>
....
<script src="~/Scripts/Knockout.mapping-2.4.1.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Authors">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text:FirstName"></td> <!--Not really using Models-->
            <td data-bind="text:LastName"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error in the console? I see a reference of KnockoutMapping, where is the reference of Knockout.js?

Comment: Yes I have added in bundle. It worked when i changed the foreach: $data. Now I am trying to add methods in my viewmodel, while having mapping from model. this is what i am trying. <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

        function viewModel() {
            this.details = function () {
                alert("de");
            };
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel,jsonModel );
    });
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You forget to map your MVC model to knockout model since knockout needs to create observable properties for all the MVC model properties:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
```

I think replacing you script with this should do the trick (As you probably see I used JQuery here):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {  
         var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
         ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });   
</script>
```

**UPDATE** Adding methods to viemodel:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function viewModel() {
    this.details = function () {
        alert("de");
    };
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Encode(Model))';

    //Map MVC model:
    var mvcModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(json);

    //create view model that contains extension methods:
    var myViewModel = new viewModel();

    //update this model with properties from MVC model:
    var koModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(myViewModel, mvcModel);

    ko.applyBindings(koModel );
});        
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Art. You suggestion did help and also when I change foreach: $data, it worked. Can you please help me last puzzle. I am trying to add methods in my viewmodel, while mapping model. I read docs, but not able to make it work. This is what I am trying. <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var jsonModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));

        function viewModel() {
            this.details = function () {
                alert("de");
            };
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel,jsonModel );
    });
</script>